# Google actions not available in google assistant for test project

Tags: actions-on-google

I am able to run the simulator on my test project within the console actions webpage. However when I test it on the google assistant app on my phone, the test project opens and replies “this application isn’t available in your country”. I am located in Canada.

Would appreciate any assistance on why this restriction is coming up.

Comment: Did you check your country in "Location targeting" tab in Actions on Google console?

Comment: Yes, all countries have been selected.

Answer (score 0):

I changed my phone language from English (Canada) to English (US) and it works. I’m not sure why English isn’t universal but at any rate that solved the problem!